# how to compare each elements in two array and find out which element is not equal without using loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There are two array ,i want to compare each elements in two array and find out which element is not equal without using loop

for example ,in the following array ,

```
a=np.array    ([1,2,5,0,1,2])
b=np.array   ([1,3,5,1,0,0])
```

the correct result should be [False  True False True True  True]

What I want is something like this

```
mask = np.in1d(a,b ,invert=True)

print(mask)
```

However,the mask output is [False  True False False False  True]

the output of mask[3]and mask[4] should be true

what can i do to compare each element in each position?i can only use numpy

like 1st element in a compare to 1st element in b

like 2nd element in a compare to 2nd element in b

like 3nd element in a compare to 3nd element in b

Answer (score 2):

Simply use !=

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 5, 0, 1, 2])
b = np.array([1, 3, 5, 1, 0, 0])
c = a != b
```

c:

```
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: its seems so easy......and i am so stupid.... thankyoU!

Comment: You're welcome. Not stupid, I think it's not intuitive if you think about arrays in the classical way :)